# How to update struct fields in a type switch in Go?

Tags: go, struct, type-switch

I want to make a function that takes in different commodity Struct and encrypts their ids.
I have a encryption function:

```
func encryption(in string, typeOf string) string {
    result := in + typeOf
    return result
}
```

and 2 commodity Struct:

```
type cloth struct {
    clothId   string
    name string
}

type pants struct {
    pantsId   string
    name string
}
```

I want to modify them through a function, by passing in variadic parameters, to perform different operations, it should modify the id of the Struct

```
func encryptId(in interface{}) {
    switch in.(type) {
    case cloth:
        in.clothId = encryption(in.clothId, "cloth")
    case pants:
        in.pantsId = encryption(in.pantsId, "pants")
    default:
        return
    }
}
```

But although this function can determine the type, it cannot modify them, how can I do?

I found [these](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-find-the-type-of-struct-in-golang/) online, but it can only judge and not modify.
I hope after doing this

```
func main() {
    clo := cloth{"cloth", "blue"}
    pan := pants{"pants", "green"}
    encryptId(clo)
    encryptId(pan)
    fmt.Println(clo)
    fmt.Println(pan)
}
```

it will output

> {clothcloth blue}
> {pantspants green}

Comment: It cannot modify them because they are copies. Use pointers instead. E.g. `encryptId(&clo)` and inside the function's `switch` use `case *cloth:`.

Comment: If the pointer is passed in, the type cannot be determined

Comment: It can, if done properly. Edit the question by adding your updated code.

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/4uYzqZ0BKVy (note the assignment in the switch statement, i.e. `switch in := in.(type) {`)

Comment: Please don't add solutions inside the question. Post an answer instead

Answer (score 0):

Solved by mkopriva

> It cannot modify them because they are copies. Use pointers instead.
> E.g. encryptId(&clo) and inside the function's switch use case *cloth:
>
> go.dev/play/p/4uYzqZ0BKVy (note the assignment in the switch
> statement, i.e. switch in := in.(type) {)

```
func encryptId(in interface{}) {
    switch s := in.(type) {
    case *cloth:
        s.id = encryption(s.id, "key")
    case *pants:
        s.id = encryption(s.id, "key")
    default:
        return
    }
}
 
func main() {
    clo := cloth{"cloth", "blue"}
    pan := pants{"pants", "green"}
    encryptId(&clo)
    encryptId(&pan)
    fmt.Println(clo)
    fmt.Println(pan)
}
```